# Android trace file created but zero bytes long

Tags: android, debugging, trace

I am trying to follow the instructions on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to create a trace file. I can see the file in File Explorer in DDMS and can pull it onto my PC but it is zero bytes long.

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong, please?

Comment: Two things I can think of: (1) Are you using the Debug class properly? We can't tell without at least a code snippet. (2) there may still be open file handles; try turning off tracing, unmounting the SD card, and reading the file via USB mass storage

Comment: The Debug code I have is (1) `import android.os.Debug;` (2) in the main Activity's onCreate: `Debug.startMethodTracing("mymap");` (after the super.onCreate call) (3) in onDestroy `Debug.stopMethodTracing();` as the final statement (4) in the manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>` and `android:debuggable="true"`. After running the App the trace file appears on the SD card. On the phone Astro file manager confirms it has zero bytes, as does Windows Explorer when I attach the phone to my PC. How do I unmount SD card from emulator?

Comment: According to the developer.android.com page on TraceView the app has to call stopMethodTracing() to cause the trace to be written to the trace file. Am I right in thinking that by pressing the Home button I should cause my app's main activity to be destroyed and therefore stopMethodTracing should be called from the statement that I have put in onDestroy?

Comment: I've just noticed that when I try to debug the app the last statement that appears on the Console is "Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.xxxxx.yyyy' on port 8600". (The same thing happens on phone and emulator). Does the fact that nothing else appears mean that the debugger fails to start properly? If so, I presume this might have some connection with the fact that the trace file is empty! How should I go about debugging the failure of the debugger to start!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to have been that the stopMethodTracing() call which I had put in the onDestroy() method (as suggested in the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html)) failed to stop the tracing even though I had tried three different means of ending the activity ... rotating the screen, pressing the Home Key and using Taskiller to kill the app.

By moving the stopMethodTracing() elsewhere I now have a trace with data in it!

(The vital clue was that I noticed that LogCat was reporting TRACE STARTED but never reported TRACE STOPPED.)

Comment: Word to the wise, initially I assumed this was my problem as well, but I found that in my case my code was just never calling stopMethodTracing.

Answer (score 1):

I called `Debug.startMethodTracing();` in the Application, and my app has multiple processes. This leads to `Debug.stopMethodTracing();` not taking effect.

Only call in the main process to solve this problem.