# Android LogCat: TextLayoutCache::replaceThai and error opening trace file

Tags: android, logging, logcat

Can somebody please explain these Log in LogCat. It's really annoying and I can't find anything about it on google.
This does not happen on emulated devices, but it happens on my Galaxy S3.
Examples of the Logs are as follows:

```
03-07 15:15:09.480: E/Trace(4912): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-07 15:15:09.565: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 74
03-07 15:15:09.565: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 74
03-07 15:15:09.565: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[1] is 61
03-07 15:15:09.565: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 74
03-07 15:15:09.565: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[1] is 61
03-07 15:15:09.565: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[2] is 43
03-07 15:15:09.570: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 21
03-07 15:15:09.570: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 21
03-07 15:15:09.570: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[1] is 64
03-07 15:15:09.570: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 21
03-07 15:15:09.570: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[1] is 64
03-07 15:15:09.570: D/TextLayoutCache(4912): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[2] is 6c
```

I can't find anything in my code that is in Thai. It fills up the LogCat so I have to find my logs...

Also I can't find anything on "trace" file.

If anyone can explain this and how to get rid of it, it would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Webb

Comment: Possibly similar issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180387/android-trace-file-created-but-zero-bytes-long